# Ansible include vars file

Tags: ansible

I am a newbie to Ansible,I was working on an automation piece, where my role takes variables from a yaml through `include_vars` module, and I have a use case where one of the variable (`dbpassword`) within that yaml file changes based on what my automation is doing and needs to be dynamic.
 Example below

```yaml
dbname: mydb
dbpassword: mydbpassword
port: 1009
```

How can I achieve making the `dbpassword` dynamic instead of being static and be populated at runtime based on source?

Comment: To be honest, I have never needed `include_vars`.  Ever.  Put what you need in the inventory.  Then you can over-ride those values with `--extra-vars` on the command line if you absolutely have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [prompt](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html) to input variable value:

```
  vars_prompt:

    - name: dbpassword
      prompt: "What is your dbpassword?"
      private: no
```